# Can't boot up rails server or rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, bundle, gemfile

After cloning an application and successfully running bundle, I've been tying to boot up my rails server but I keep on getting an error message.

I've tried updating bundle, uninstalling bundle and reinstalling it, and removing the gemfile.lock and rerunning bundle but nothing seems to work. Thank you!

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:45:in `full_gem_path': uninitialized constant Bundler::Plugin::API::Source (NameError)

from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:145:in `block in full_require_paths'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:144:in `map'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:144:in `full_require_paths'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:77:in `contains_requirable_file?'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:949:in `block in find_in_unresolved'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:949:in `each'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:949:in `find_all'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:949:in `find_in_unresolved'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:74:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/plugin/api/source.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:45:in `full_gem_path'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:145:in `block in full_require_paths'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:144:in `map'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:144:in `full_require_paths'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1370:in `add_self_to_load_path'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1283:in `activate'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `block in gem'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `synchronize'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `gem'
from /Users/GrandsonBoom/Desktop/brogrammer/Viafly-Server/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a specific broken version of `bundler` gem. I suggest you do these 2 steps:

`$ gem uninstall bundler
$ gem install bundler`